# how combine 'utf-8' and 'unicode_escape' to correctly decode b'\xc3\xa4\\n-\\t-\\"foo\\"'?

Tags: string, python-3.x, encoding, escaping

I have a library that gives me encoded and escaped byte sequences like this one:

```
a=b'\xc3\xa4\\n-\\t-\\"foo\\"'
```

Which I want to translate back to:

```
ä
-   -"foo"
```

I tried to just `.decode` a which *decodes* the sequence as wanted:

```
>>> a.decode()
'ä\\n-\\t-\\"foo\\"'
```

But it does not un-escape. Then I found `'unicode_escape'` and I got

```
>>> print(a.decode('unicode_escape'))
Ã¤
-   -"foo"
```

Is there a way to decode and unescape the given sequence with a builtin method (i.e. without having to `.replace('\\n', '\n').replace(...)`)?

It would be also interesting to know how I can revert this operation (i.e. getting the same byte sequence from the translated result).

Comment: Sorry - your question is not understandable after your "edit" - you provided an answer, and them changed the problem you have. One can't know what you want.

Comment: Better now? I intended to provide a *possible* solution which shows what I try to achieve. It was not the answer I was hoping to find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to *somehow* do what I want and I can *almost* go the other way, too but in my eyes it's ugly and incomplete, so I hope it's not the best option I have:

```
>>> import codecs
>>> decoded = codecs.escape_decode(a)[0].decode()
>>> print(decoded)
ä
-   -"foo"
>>> reencoded = codecs.escape_encode(decoded.encode())
>>> print(reencoded)
(b'\\xc3\\xa4\\n-\\t-"foo"', 11)      <--- qotes are note escaped
```

Comment: This is the only way I have found to make this work, yet it is actually an undocumented private internal function: https://bugs.python.org/issue30588