# How to decode u'\xc3\xa9cosyst\xc3\xa8mes' to utf-8

Tags: python, python-2.7, encoding, escaping

From webscraping with BeautifulSoup, I get a query string parameter that end up being represented as:

```
param_value = u'\xc3\xa9cosyst\xc3\xa8mes'
```

When reading it, I can guess that it should be represented as `écosytèmes`

I tried several way to encode / escape / decode (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41160817/how-combine-utf-8-and-unicode-escape-to-correctly-decode-b-xc3-xa4-n-t) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39035899/how-to-decode-string-representative-of-utf-8-with-python))

But I keep on getting errors like:

```
UnicodeEncodeError('ascii', u'\xc3\xa9cosyst\xc3\xa8mes', 0, 2, 'ordinal not in range(128)')
```

I also tried the solution proposed as duplicate:

```
Python 2.7.15 (default, Jul 23 2018, 21:27:06)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.2)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> s = u'\xc3\xa9cosyst\xc3\xa8mes'
>>> s.encode('latin-1').decode('utf-8')
u'\xe9cosyst\xe8mes'
```

but it gets me back to square 1...

How can I get from `u'\xc3\xa9cosyst\xc3\xa8mes'` to `u'écosystèmes'`?

Comment: Related: [Fixing mojibakes in UTF-8 text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48430825/fixing-mojibakes-in-utf-8-text). What you have looks like UTF-8 decoded as latin-1.

Comment: `u'\xe9cosyst\xe8mes'` is the correct unicode string value. You should now read [Understanding repr( ) function in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7784148/understanding-repr-function-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have UTF-8 decoded as latin-1, so the solution is to encode as latin-1 then decode as UTF-8.

```
>>> s = u'\xc3\xa9cosyst\xc3\xa8mes'
>>> s.encode('latin-1').decode('utf-8')
u'\xe9cosyst\xe8mes'
>>> print s.encode('latin-1').decode('utf-8')
écosystèmes
```

Comment: it only only gets me back to square 1...

```
>>> s = u'\xc3\xa9cosyst\xc3\xa8mes'
>>> s.encode('latin-1')
'\xc3\xa9cosyst\xc3\xa8mes'
>>> s.encode('latin-1').decode('utf-8')
u'\xe9cosyst\xe8mes'
```

Comment: That's not square one - that's the solution. The `repr` doesn't necessarily show the decoded text; but try to `print` it (on a device which can handle Unicode).

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help: `bytes(u'\xc3\xa9cosyst\xc3\xa8mes', 'latin-1').decode('utf-8')`

Comment: It will, trivially, if you can figure out how to convert the `u''` string in the question into this `b''` bytestring; but that is obviously the nontrivial crux of this question.

Comment: Like so: `bytes(u'\xc3\xa9cosyst\xc3\xa8mes', 'latin-1').decode('utf-8')`
This should work now